# Here why is it wrong to differentiate both sides and put $x=2$ to find $g'(2)$?

Tags: calculus

Here why is it wrong to differentiate both sides and put $x=2$ to find $g'(2)$?

> If $\displaystyle I = \int \frac{x-1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}} \,\mathrm dx = g(x) + c$, then $\left\lfloor \dfrac{1}{g'(2)} \right\rfloor = \cdots$,
> (where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ represents the greatest integer function)

To me it seemed like it's an identity and so it should be safe to differentiate both sides.

Comment: What did you get when you differentiated both sides?

Comment: Can you see the image that I have posted?

Comment: @satyamsharma the image doesn't show your answer.

Comment: @hardmath I am getting g'(2)=1/3sqrt(14) after differentiating. The actual answer says g'(2)=1/3

Comment: Likely a misprint.  But again, that's not what the problem shown asks for.

Comment: Looks like $0$  is answer.

Comment: @hardmath I know how to take the floor of that. But when you do actually integrate to get g(x) and evaluate g' from there and substitute 2 then g'(2) comes out as 1/3. New to this platform so don't know how to post the solution pic here.

Comment: @herbsteinberg no it's not. Answer given at the source is 3

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks a lot

Comment: They have made a mistake in the solution.....source was pretty authentic so didn't doubt their solution..... Sorry guys for wasting your time

Comment: I've converted the image to $\LaTeX$ above to get you started.  I also get $g'(2) = \frac{1}{3\sqrt{14}}$.

Comment: Forgot reciprocal.  Answer is 11.

Comment: It seems to me nobody is guilty of wasting anyone's time, except perhaps the person who put the wrong answer in the problem source in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\int \frac{x-1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}} \,\mathrm dx = g(x) + c
$$
$$
\frac{x-1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}} = g'(x)
$$
$$
\frac 1 {3\sqrt{14}} = g'(2)
$$
$$
\frac 1 {g'(2)} = 3\sqrt{14}, \text{ which is between 11 and 12}
$$
$$
\left\lfloor \frac 1 {g'(2)} \right\rfloor = 11
$$

**Addendum :**

$$\begin{align}
11=\sqrt{121}&<\sqrt{126}=\sqrt{2\cdot3^2\cdot7}=3\sqrt{14}=\\
&=\sqrt{126}<\sqrt{144}=12
\end{align}$$

$\text{hence ,}$

$$11<3\sqrt{14}<12\;.$$

Comment: **Addendum :**

$$\begin{align}
11=\sqrt{121}&<\sqrt{126}=\sqrt{2\cdot3^2\cdot7}=3\sqrt{14}=\\
&=\sqrt{126}<\sqrt{144}=12
\end{align}$$

$\text{hence ,}$

$$11<3\sqrt{14}<12\;.$$

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is correct.The formula given clearly indicates that $g(x)$ is the indefinite integral of the function:

$$ \frac{x-1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}} $$

So differentiating $g(x)$ gives us back that function of $x$, and evaluating it at $x=2$ after differentiation is correct.

We should get $g'(2) = \frac{1}{3\sqrt{14}}$, and the greatest integer function applied to the reciprocal gives us $\lfloor 3\sqrt{14} \rfloor = 11$.

**Addendum :**

$$\begin{align}
11=\sqrt{121}&<\sqrt{126}=\sqrt{2\cdot3^2\cdot7}=3\sqrt{14}=\\
&=\sqrt{126}<\sqrt{144}=12
\end{align}$$

$\text{hence ,}$

$$11<3\sqrt{14}<12\;.$$

Comment: **Addendum :**

$$\begin{align}
11=\sqrt{121}&<\sqrt{126}=\sqrt{2\cdot3^2\cdot7}=3\sqrt{14}=\\
&=\sqrt{126}<\sqrt{144}=12
\end{align}$$

$\text{hence ,}$

$$11<3\sqrt{14}<12\;.$$

Comment: @Angelo: I think you are a bit overzealous in repeating that computation four times between both Answers.

Comment: hardmath, I am not a bit overzealous, actually I am a lot. Of course, you can delete my addendum from your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot people...